# NO Flexform (pi_flexform) Field in BE Permission Settings

Tags: plugins, permissions, typo3, settings

I developed a FE Plugin which should be configurable by the editor via flexform settings (pi_flexform field in the tt_content table). Similar to tt_news or news Extension. Everything working great as Admin, but it is not possible to active the Flexform for another user... The plugin can be selected but the flexform will not render... How can I enable the flexform field.

Add. Comment: There is no table field pi_flexform in the permission settings for a BE User Group!

Please Help
Working and tested TYPO3 6.2.5 und 7.6.9

German Maillist Question:
https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/215053/

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the TCA for the field has a setting `$GLOBALS[TCA][<table>][columns][<field>][exclude] = 1`. Otherwise it will not be listed in the BE user settings.

Comment: Thx for the fast response...
I added the code to the ext_tables.php of my extension: 
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['pi_flexform']['exclude'] = 0;
Sorry this has no effect... 

I tested the tt_news extension either. It seems that there is the same issue. The tt_content field "pi_flexform" is not available as a normal BE User...

Any other suggestions?